# AngularJS Directives and IIFE Closures

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build an angular app "the right way" using various style guides as my inspiration. [John Papa's](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#iife) being the most notable. Most say I should wrap angular components in Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE) and separate them into different files. This works on everything except directives.

**Am I doing something wrong or if I should not use IIFEs for directives or use them in a different way?**

Here is my jfiddle of it not working:
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14140/

Here is my jfiddle with it working without IIFEs:
http://jsfiddle.net/8kfpf9aq/

The only difference is wrapping in:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    //code

});
```

I have tried it and it works similarly in several version of angular 1, 1.3, 1.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem might be that you're not invoking the IIFE. It should look like this

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    //code

})();
```

or this

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    //code

}).call(this);
```

Comment: It happens to the best of us :)

Comment: Invoking an IIFE would turn it into an IIIFE ^^